# Can not screen scrape

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I'm not very advanced with `PHP` and I am trying to figure out *Screen Scraping*.  I have read lots of tutorials and searched this site, but there is something I'm missing. My code will just not work.

This is what I'm trying:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$html->load_file('http://www.website.com/item.htm');  

$price = $html->find('itemprop="price"');
echo $price;
```

The source of the site I am trying to use is:

```
<span itemprop="price">$20.99</span>
```

When I run this `$price` is set to `Array`.

Why is this not working for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working, just not how you expect.

The `find` method is returning an array of results (since there maybe 0, 1 or *n* elements with `itemprop="price"` in the page.

For example:

```
foreach($html->find('itemprop="price"') as $price) 
   echo $price;
```

Comment: Well, how many elements are in `$html->find('itemprop="price"')`?

Comment: count() does help.  There are 0 elements, so I guess my error is in the find function.  Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out!  I was passing the wrong information to the find function.  The correct code was:

    $price = $html->find('span[itemprop=price]');